# Auth: Does using session and cookie when moving from one page to another is secure?

Tags: php, session, authentication, cookies

Once user login, i set session key and cookie, and always check while traversing from one page to another whether session key is set or not and allow user access to data.

If user doesn't logout and close the browser, session key destroys but cookies remain their. So when again user open browser, first i check whether session key is present or not, if not, then check for cookie. If cookie is present, again set session key for this instance and give him access based on previous method.

When user logout, just delete both cookie and session key.

In case cookies are disabled, this method works fine, as only deal with sessions.

**Is this the securest method everyone uses for their website?? Can i improve this to make my website more secure?**

Comment: With session key, do you mean passing the session id via GET parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use only session, without session key. PHP creates cookie called "session id" when you write "session_start".

Comment: Hi sir, Thanks for your answer. Do you want to say that i should only use session? Is it safe? I used cookie for remembering user data, can i do it with sessions.

Comment: so what method one should use for remembering user for later sessions? I am encrypting data in cookie and when it is changed, not giving authorization to user, hope this if fine?

Comment: use Symmetric-key algorithm to encrypt the data into a cookie.

Comment: Encrypting data in a cookie is not necessary just to remember the user. It's a better approach to generate a random token like a valet service.